# Kann „sich lassen“ unter allen Umständen verwendet werden?

Tags: sentence-structure

After hours of struggling with *sich* *lassen*, I feel less discombobulated with the inherent intricacy of this alien structure both in Persian and English. Yet, given the novelty of this syntax in my head, I feel disconcerted whenever I attempt to use it freely with whatever transitive verb I get my hands on. Here is where I saw the structure for the first time:

> Es machte mißmutig, nicht zu wissen, was sich tun ließ, nicht zu
> wissen welche Vorteile für ihren Vater und sie aus den Veränderungen
> erwachsen würden.

Based on what my mind will have gathered, I wrote the following sentences:

> Ich weiß nicht, warum sich das Essen  nicht verdauen lässt.
>
> Ich glaube, dein Haus wird sich nicht verkaufen lassen.
>
> Ich bin sicher, dass Arsenal sich nicht besiegt lassen wird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Ich weiß nicht, warum sich das Essen nicht verdauen lässt.

Correct. ✓

> Ich glaube, dein Haus wird sich nicht verkaufen lassen.

Correct. ✓

> Ich bin sicher, dass Arsenal sich nicht besiegt lassen wird.

Ich bin sicher, dass Arsenal sich nicht besieg**en** lassen wird.

You wrote you have already wrapped your mind around this, but as an explanation, this **sich lassen** comes from a passive sentence with **werden können**.

> Ich weiß nicht, warum das Essen nicht verdaut werden kann.
>
> Ich glaube, dein Haus wird nicht verkauft werden können.
>
> Ich bin sicher, dass Arsenal nicht besiegt werden können wird.

All these sentences are correct but sound incredibly awkward in German speaker's ears. We just hate passive voice. So, yes, you can **and should** use **sich + <infinitive> + lassen** with any infinitive or infinitive based insert.

> Ich bin sicher, dass Arsenal sich diesmal nicht wieder die Butter vom Brot nehmen lassen wird.

(*die Butter vom Brot nehmen* == (pic.) steal the price from you right in front of your mouth. Typical football reporter speech.)

Comment: Vielen Dank. Just one pretty off-topic question regarding the position of sich in dependent clauses. Is it grammatically possible to bring sich after das Essen in the first example or in the example of Arsenal before Arsenal?

Comment: @user26231 Yes, both variants are possible and correct, too.